# Critical sections and shutdown / destruction?

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, mutex, critical-section

I can't figure out what a proper shutdown procedure is when you have an object OBJ1 which contains a critical section CS and a pointer to another object OBJ2

Say you have two functions A and B.

A enters the critical section, modifies data in OBJ2 and leaves the critical section.
B is a shutdown/destruction procedure and is supposed to destroy everything (OBJ2, CS and OBJ1)

My question is :

How do you solve the scenario where A is waiting to enter the critical section because B already entered it? B will destroy everything. If the 'destruction' (for some funny reason) causes/allows A to enter the critical section, then A will generate an exception since it is trying access an object which no longer exists. If the 'destruction' doesn't cause A to enter the critical section, then A just hangs forever waiting to enter the critical section.

What is the proper way to destroy an instance of a class which contains a critical section and a pointer to an object?

To me it seems like the only solution is to have the critical section as a global variable while the data can be put in a "class" (structure)....but I don't like that solution!

The language I'm using is C. I know that you don't have classes in C. I have instances of structures.

Example:

```
typedef struct classX_t
{
   CRITICAL_SECTION cs;
   classY* thisY;
} classX;


typedef struct classY_t
{
   int some_variable;
} classY;
```

I create an instance of X and an instance of Y. The variable 'thisY' points to the instance of Y. My two functions are:

```
void funcA(classX* thisClassX)
{
   if (thisClassX == NULL) return;
   EnterCriticalSection(thisClassX->cs);

   thisClassX->thisY->some_variable++;

   LeaveCriticalSection(thisClass->cs);
}


void funcB(classX* thisClassX)
{
   if (thisClassX == NULL) return;
   EnterCriticalSection(thisClassX->cs);
   /* free stuff here */
   free(thisClassX->thisY);
   DeleteCriticalSection(thisClass->cs);
   /* and destroy instance */
   free(thisClassX)
}
```

If funcA is waiting to enter the critical section because B already entered the critical section, then I don't see how funcA can properly execute without causing problems. What is the solution to this?

EDIT:

Maybe I need some kind of "lock" count; i.e. a counter which increments by 1 when some code enters a critical section and decrements when the code leaves the critical section? If I had that, then the shutdown procedure could check the count to see if it is greater than 1 (indicating that some other code is waiting to enter the critical section) and if the count is > 1 then it could sleep until the count goes back down to 1. So here's what I'm suggesting:

Each function does this:

```
void someFunction(...)
{
    if (thisClassX == NULL) return;
    thisClassX->counter++;
    EnterCriticalSection(thisClassX->cs);
    /* do something */
    LeaveCriticalSection(thisClassX->cs);
    thisClassX->counter--;
}
```

Comment: "...destroy an instance of a class..." So, this *isn't* a C language question ?

Comment: as WhozCraig said, could you be more specific, because as it is it's not quite clear what you're talking about and some code snipped would also be splendid

Comment: This is a pretty common problem, you thought of everything but overlooked program shutdown.  No magic solution for that, and often very difficult to solve because the exit request is so completely asynchronous.  Other than exit(0);  Enshrined in C++11 as well with std::quick_exit()

Comment: Actually there exists a magic solution. Simply delete everything inside B in any order you like. The reason is obvious: It is not possible to do this in a safe way unless the thread that calls B is the only thread running (or the only thread running that may call A). Which means you must necessarily have exited all other threads already, and so it is not necessary to synchronize anything. If there are other threads running (which may call A), it doesn't matter whether the objects are "safely" accessed and deleted via the CS. It will result in accessing an _invalid_ object either way.

Comment: @Damon : So if A is waiting to enter the critical section because B already entered it, there's no solution to that problem? A is simply going to generate an exception if and when it tries to access invalid data ? Please confirm.

Comment: The shutdown thread (B) should signal the other threads (like A) that they need to abandon their work ASAP.  Then B waits for all the other threads to exit and then does its work.

Comment: The thread calling B will delete the objects. It may do that "safely" by acquiring the CS first, so it will not delete the object while thread-calling-A is using the object. **But:** There is no way of knowing that B doesn't delete the object first, and _then_ A (which checked for a nullpointer _before entering the CS_) tries to use it. At the very least, _everything_, including nullpointer checks in both functions must be completely inside the CS, then it _should_ work (it's still not something that makes me happy design-wise).

Comment: The critical section is irrelevant to your problem.  Once function B calls `free()`, any attempt by another thread to use `thisClassX` is a bug, including but not limited to trying to enter the critical section.  Sounds like you need to do some kind of reference counting.  Note that it is *not* the number of threads inside the critical section that you need to count, but the number of threads that might try to use the given instance of `thisClassX` in *any way whatsoever*.

Comment: @Harry : That was also the conclusion I arrived at.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add a switch (an integer or whatever you prefer) which tells each function if it is still valid/ allowed to alter your OBJ.